# how to pass domnode to the sub window created by window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

when we appendChild in B.js,there is an undefined error！

```
//sample code    
//A.js
this.node = document.getElementById("area");
window.open("B.html");

//B.js
document.getElementById("area").appendChild(window.opener.node);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document` in *B.js* is a different *#document* to the one in *A.js*. This means `window.opener.node` is a *Node* from a different *#document* and therefore you have to call [`document.importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode) on it before you can use it here

```
// B.js
var node = document.importNode(window.opener.node, /* deep */ true);
document.getElementById("area").appendChild(node);
```

Please note that this new *Node* is a **copy**, if you have large structures you may wish to also destroy the original.

---

If you want to support old IE browsers that have reached their end of life, here are some shims

---

Using a `<div>` and setting it's `innerHTML`

```
if (!document.importNode) {
    document.importNode = function (node, deep) {
        var wrapper_old = node.ownerDocument.createElement('div'),
            wrapper_new = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper_old.appendChild(node.cloneNode(!!deep));
        wrapper_new.innerHTML = wrapper_old.innerHTML;
        return wrapper_new.removeChild(wrapper_new.firstChild);
    };
}
```

It should work on everything that can be a child of `<div>`

---

Invoking `cloneNode` from your new *#document* (I haven't tested it)

```
if (!document.importNode) {
    document.importNode = function (node, deep) {
        return Node.prototype.cloneNode.call(node, !!deep);
    };
}
```

Assuming it works, it will work for more *Nodes*, but will drop *id attributes*.

---

A custom import/clone function (this will clone *id attributes*)

```
if (!document.importNode) {
    document.importNode = function (node, deep) {
        var e, i, a;
        if (node.nodeType === 3) // #text
            return document.createTextNode(node.data);
        if (node.nodeType === 8) // #comment
            return document.createComment(node.data);
        if (node.nodeType !== 1) // #document/other
            throw new TypeError('Unsupported nodeType: ' + node.nodeType);
        // Element
        e = document.createElement(node.tagName);
        a = node.attributes;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            e.setAttribute(a[i].name, a[i].value);
        }
        if (deep)
            for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                e.appendChild(clone(node.childNodes[i]));
            }
        return e;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but IE does not support this method.  (document.importNode)

Comment: @gaoyanmin IE9 supports it, IE<7 have reached end of life, IE8 should only be used in businesses where they're unable to upgrade for whatever reason

Comment: @gaoyanmin wrote a polyfill

Comment: thanks.We will try it later.Another problem is how can we pass the related things(for example,a timer on the window, some variables...and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you will get and undefined error. Because there are 2 different files. The new opened window does not have access to the other HTML elements(say A.html).

The element with id area should be present in the HTML. Otherwise it will give undefined error. you can try with iframe you can access the elements of iframe and you can append data to the node.

```
window.frames['iframe'].document.getElementsByTagName('body')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Notice that the "area" div is removed from A.html

A.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="area">test</div>
<script>
this.node = document.getElementById("area");
window.open("B.html");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And B.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="area1"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("area1").appendChild(window.opener.node);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```